# Definition button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-editor

Since this is a documentation site, wouldn't make sense to have a 'definition' button in the editor toolbar?

I know we have the definition list tags (<dl>,<dt>,<dd>) but I think their use should be encouraged here. Having a button like the ones for code and lists would make it a lot easier.

---

Definition tags

<dl>,<dt>,<dd>

Underused tags with (apparently) no particular styling on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where do you see these tags having a deeper meaning within Documentation? Syntax/Parameters are already separate sections with distinct styling. A before/after of an existing piece of docs with definition tags vs without would be helpful here to flesh out the feature request.

Comment: OK, i just found out about those. Here is the link for anyone else who does not know about these: http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-anatomy
I will check how things really work then come back to this